# Gatsby Deployment on AWS - Segmentation Fault and Unexpected Server Shutdown

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I'm currently facing issues with deploying my Gatsby application on AWS. I have successfully deployed the application, but I encounter a segmentation fault error with the message "1|gatsby | segmentation fault (core dumped)" when running the Gatsby command. Additionally, the server unexpectedly shuts down after a couple of minutes.

Steps I've Taken:

Deployed the Gatsby application on AWS.
Used PM2 to run Gatsby, and it runs fine initially.
However, the server unexpectedly goes down after a few minutes.
Error Messages:

```
segmentation fault (core dumped) error command failed with exit code 139. gatsby
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a memory issue to me. How much RAM do you have on the AWS instance? Have you monitored RAM usage while the site is running? You can do this using `top` or `htop`.

If you don't want to move your site to a larger EC2 instance you can cater for insufficient RAM by adding some swap space. See, for example, [these instructions](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2021/06/adding-swap/).